# SkiaSharp Xamarin: InvalidateSurface() works on android but not on ios device

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

i've made a Xamarin app which includes a graph drawn by a SkiaSharp SKCanvas. Now i have the following issue:

According to documentation and tutorials it is necessary to call `InvalidateSurface()`Then the `OnPaintSurface()`is called which can be overridden. This call works fine on emulators and on android devices. But as soon as I deploy the app to my iPhone (iOs 13.3) `OnPaintSurface()` is never called. `InvalidateSurface()` is called by change of a dependency property.

Anyone some advice or experience to this weird behaviour?

Code snippet:

```
 public class CoordAxesControl : SKCanvasView
{
    private float _absoluteMinXOfCoord;
    private float _absoluteMaxXOfCoord;
    private float _absoluteMinYOfCoord;
    private float _absoluteMaxYOfCoord;
    private SKPaint _blackPaint;


    #region DependencyProperties

    public static readonly BindableProperty PointCoordinatesProperty = 
                BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: nameof(PointCoordinates),
                    returnType: typeof(IEnumerable<Tuple<int,int>>),
                    defaultValue: new List<Tuple<int,int>>(),
                    declaringType: typeof(CoordAxesControl),
                    propertyChanged: DependencyPropertiesChanged);

    public IEnumerable<Tuple<int,int>> PointCoordinates
    {
        get { return _pointCoordinates; }
        set { _pointCoordinates = value; }
    }
    private IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> _pointCoordinates;

    #endregion

    #region methods
    private static void DependencyPropertiesChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (CoordAxesControl)bindable;

        if (oldValue != newValue)
        {
            control.PointCoordinates = (List<Tuple<int, int>>)newValue;
            control.InvalidateSurface();
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Called method when canvas is drawn
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnPaintSurface(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PointCoordinates == null)
            return;

        var canvas = e.Surface.Canvas;
        canvas.Clear();

        _blackPaint = new SKPaint();
        _blackPaint.Color = SKColors.Black;
        _blackPaint.StrokeWidth = 5;
        //drawing canvas is placed here. Omitted due to clarity
```

Comment: instead of describing the code, show us the relevant portions

Comment: @Jason I've added the relevant code snippet

Comment: @CJThiele Hi, do you have a try with other iPhone devices with different software version to test ? And whether occur error logs when running in physical device .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I tried it with an iPhone SE but unfortunately it was the same iOs edition as installed on my iPhone 8 so it doesnt work either.  Now i tried it on an Huawei Mate 10 and on Android its working with no problems... So this has to be an iOs specific problem

Comment: @CJThiele OK , if you can share a sample project link here , I will check it in my local site . By the way , you not need to share your current project , just re-create a new project with this issue .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Github Repo Link: https://github.com/Christoph293/infoGraph   Thank you :)

Comment: @CJThiele Hi , thanks for sharing . However , it works in my local site no matter in simulator or physical device . I think you can share the unlaunched screenshot here to check .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT What do you mean with unlaunched screenshot? Is it possible that my mac is the problem? Is there a way to uninstall/install tools to fix this?

Comment: @CJThiele Hi , I mean you can show the screenshot of visual stuido when running in iOS device . I want to see the OutPut in console .